# Does Java have the static order initialisation fiasco?

Tags: java, singleton, static-order-fiasco

A recent question here had the following code (well, similar to this) to implement a singleton without synchronisation.

```
public class Singleton {
    private Singleton() {}
    private static class SingletonHolder { 
        private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();
    }
    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }
}
```

Now, I think understand what this is doing. Since the instance is `static final`, it's built long before any threads will call `getInstance()` so there's no real need for synchronisation.

Synchronisation would be needed only if two threads tried to call `getInstance()` at the same time (and that method did construction on first call rather than at `"static final"` time).

My question is therefore basically: why then would you ever prefer lazy construction of the singleton with something like:

```
public class Singleton {
    private Singleton() {}
    private static Singleton instance = null;
    public static synchronized Singleton getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Singleton();
        return instance;
    }
}
```

My only thoughts were that using the `static final` method may introduce sequencing issue as in the C++ static initialisation order fiasco.

First off, does Java actually *have* this problem? I know order *within* a class is fully specified but does it somehow guarantee consistent order *between* classes (such as with a class loader)?

Secondly, if the order *is* consistent, why would the lazy construction option ever be advantageous?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Now, I think understand what this is doing. Since the instance is static final, it's built long before any threads will call getInstance() so there's no real need for synchronisation.

Not quite.  It is built when the `SingletonHolder` class is [initialized](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-11-2001/jw-1102-java101.html) which happens the first time `getInstance` is called.  The classloader has a separate locking mechanism, but after a class is loaded, no further locking is needed so this scheme does just enough locking to prevent multiple instantiation.

> First off, does Java actually have this problem? I know order within a class is fully specified but does it somehow guarantee consistent order between classes (such as with a class loader)?

Java does have a problem where a class initialization cycle can lead to some class observing another class's static finals before they are initialized (technically before all static initializer blocks have run).

Consider

```
class A {
  static final int X = B.Y;
  // Call to Math.min defeats constant inlining
  static final int Y = Math.min(42, 43);
}

class B {
  static final int X = A.Y;
  static final int Y = Math.min(42, 43);
}

public class C {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.err.println("A.X=" + A.X + ", A.Y=" + A.Y);
    System.err.println("B.X=" + B.X + ", B.Y=" + B.Y);
  }
}
```

Running C prints

```
A.X=42, A.Y=42
B.X=0, B.Y=42
```

But in the idiom you posted, there is no cycle between the helper and the singleton so there is no reason to prefer lazy initialization.

Comment: I think that universal reason for lazy initialization is to defer something (potentially) expensive until absolutely needed in a hope that it would not be needed at all. Say your application wants to download something if it runs longer than x. The user can close it before x in which case the (usually expensive) connection creation would be a waste.

Comment: @Michal, if you do the computation on load of a small helper class as in the OP, then Java's lazy loading gets you all the benefits of lazy  initialization.  If it is not something that should be global w.r.t. a class loader, then that is not an option though.

Answer (score 3):

> Now, I think understand what this is
>   doing. Since the instance is static
>   final, it's built long before any
>   threads will call getInstance() so
>   there's no real need for
>   synchronisation.

No. `SingletonHolder` class will be loaded only when you invoke `SingletonHolder.INSTANCE` for the very first time. `final` Object will become visible to other threads only after it is fully constructed. Such lazy initialization is called [`Initialization on demand holder idiom`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom).

Answer (score 1):

In [*Effective Java*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/), Joshua Bloch notes that "This [idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_on_demand_holder_idiom) … exploits the guarantee that a class will not be initialized until it is used [[JLS, 12.4.1](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4.1)]."

Answer (score 1):

The patern that you described works for two reasons

1. Class is loaded and initialized when first accessed (via SingletonHolder.INSTANCE here)
2. Class loading and initialization is atomic in Java

So you do perform lazy initialization in a thread safe and efficient way. This pattern is better alternative to double lock (not working) solution to synchronized lazy init.

Answer (score 0):

You initialize eagerly because you don't have to write a synchronized block or method. This is mainly because synchronization is [generally considered expensive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671089/why-are-synchronize-expensive-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Just a little note about the first implementation: the interesting thing here is that class initialization is used to replace classical synchronization.

Class initialization is very well defined in that no code can ever get access to anything of the class unless it is fully initialized (i.e. all static initializer code has run). And since an already loaded class can be accessed with about zero overhead, this restricts the "synchronization" overhead to those cases where there is an actual check to be done (i.e. "is the class loaded/initialized yet?").

One drawback of using the class loading mechanism is that it can be hard to debug when it breaks. If, for some reason, the `Singleton` constructor throws an exception, then the *first* caller to `getInstance()` will get that exception (wrapped in another one).

The *second* caller however will **never** see the root cause of the problem (he will simply get a `NoClassDefFoundError`). So if the *first* caller somehow ignores the problem, then you'll **never** be able to find out *what exactly* went wrong.

If you use simply synchronization, then the second called will just try to instantiate the `Singleton` again and will probably run into the same problem (or even succeed!).

Answer (score 0):

The code in the first version is the *correct* and *best* way to safely lazily construct a singleton.
The Java Memory Model guarantees that INSTANCE will:

- Only be initialized when first actually used (ie lazy), because classes are loaded only when first used
- Be constructed exactly once so it's completely thread-safe, because all static initialization is guaranteed to be completed before the class is available for use

Version 1 is an excellent pattern to follow.

**EDITED**
Version 2 is thread safe, but a little bit expensive and more importantly, severely limits concurrency/throughput

Comment: maybe I don't get it, but I think the version 2 is also thread safe: public static synchronized Singleton getInstance(). It just has the overhead of synchronizing on each access.

Comment: sorry, my bad - i missed the method synch - you are both correct, it IS safe. +1 to each of you :)

Answer (score 0):

A class is initialized when it's accessed at runtime. So init order is pretty much the execution order.

"Access" here refers to limited actions [specified in the spec](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.4.1). The next section talks about initialization.

What's going on in your first example is equivalently

```
public static Singleton getSingleton()
{
    synchronized( SingletonHolder.class )
    {
        if( ! inited (SingletonHolder.class) )
            init( SingletonHolder.class );
    } 
    return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
}
```

( Once initialized, the sync block becomes useless; JVM will optimize it off. )

Semantically, this is not different from the 2nd impl. This doesn't really outshine "double checked locking", because it **is** double checked locking.

Since it piggybacks on class init semantics, it only works for static instances. In general, lazy evaluation is not limited to static instances; imagine there's an instance per session.

Answer (score 0):

> First off, does Java actually have this problem? I know order within a class is fully specified but does it somehow guarantee consistent order between classes (such as with a class loader)?

It does, but to a lesser degree than in C++:

- If there is no dependency cycle, the static initialization occurs in the right order.
- If there is a dependency cycle in the static initialization of a group of classes, then the order of initialization of the classes is indeterminate.
- However, Java guarantees that default initialization of static fields (to null / zero / false) happens before any code gets to see the values of the fields.  So a class can (in theory) be written to do the right thing irrespective of the initialization order.

> Secondly, if the order is consistent, why would the lazy construction option ever be advantageous?

Lazy initialization is useful in a number of situations:

- When the initialization has side effects that you don't want to happen *unless* the object is actually going to be used.
- When the initialization is expensive, and you don't want it to waste time doing it unnecessarily ... or you want more important things to happen sooner (e.g. displaying the UI).
- When the initialization depends on some state that is not available at static initialization time.  (Though you need to be careful with this, because the state might not be available when lazy initialization gets triggered either.)

You can also implement lazy initialization using a synchronized `getInstance()` method.  It is easier to understand, though it makes the `getInstance()` fractionally slower.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not into your code snippet, but I have an answer for your question. Yes, Java has an initialization order fiasco. I came across it with mutually dependent enums. An example would look like:

```
enum A {
  A1(B.B1);
  private final B b;
  A(B b) { this.b = b; }
  B getB() { return b; }
}

enum B {
  B1(A.A1);
  private final A a;
  B(A a) { this.a = a; }
  A getA() { return a; }
}
```

The key is that B.B1 must exist when creating instance A.A1. And to create A.A1 B.B1 must exist.

My real-life use case was bit more complicated - the relationship between the enums was in fact parent-child so one enum was returning reference to its parent, but the second array of its children. The children were private static fields of the enum. The interesting thing is that while developing on Windows everything was working fine, but in production—which is Solaris—the members of the child array were null. The array had the proper size but its elements were null because they were not available when the array was instantiated.

So I ended up with the synchronized initialization on the first call. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only correct singletone in Java can be declared not by class, but by enum:

```
public enum Singleton{
   INST;
   ... all other stuff from the class, including the private constructor
}
```

The use is as:

```
Singleton reference1ToSingleton=Singleton.INST;
```

All other ways do not exclude repeated instantiation through reflection or if the source of class is directly present in the app source. Enum excludes **everything**. ( [The final clone method in Enum ensures that enum constants can never be cloned](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.9) )