# Why StringBuilder gives better performance than StringBuffer?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, mutable, stringbuffer

My question is that many documentation over mutable strings, I have read that `StringBuilder` gives faster result as compare to `StringBuffer`. People gives reason that, `StringBuilder` is `not synchronized` and `StringBuffer` is `synchronized`, but it gives same result even with single thread. Please give me the valid reason for that.

Comment: Synchronization can have a performance penalty regardless of lock contention. See also [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java)

Comment: If you look at more than just the top answer to [Difference between StringBuilder and StringBuffer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/355089/5221149), you'll find the answers to your question. Unless you're really asking this: [Why are synchronize expensive in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1671089/5221149)

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it gives same result even with single thread"? Showing your code/work on the test case(s) you are running might help you get more pertinent answers.

Comment: Don't use `StringBuffer`. There's really no use case for it.