# Difference between Lock and synchronize

Tags: synchronize, reentrancy

In an interview I was asked about the difference between Lock and synchronize.
Which will I should prefer.
Logically I find both as same. We can achieve all the task using any of them. But not able to answer what he wants to listen.

Answer (score 0):

Locking and Synchronize achieve the same thing, but synchronize is less efficient. You can read more about why synchronize is expensive in java from this answer here: [Why are synchronize expensive in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671089/why-are-synchronize-expensive-in-java)